# Detailed info on IPX/SPX

Tags: networking

All these days I've been looking for some good information on IPX/SPX protocol stack but the information is very limited. I mean, the Wikipedia article contains barely one paragraph on info, and the rest is all about implementation.

Anyone knows whether there exists any source to get long & detailed information on IPX/SPX?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IPX came out of Xerox, and it was used in a major way in Netware until they saw the light. You should be able to find it all somewhere at [Novell](http://novell.com). If not I think I still have a shelf-ful of IPX/SPX books from twenty years ago that you can have for the price of the postage.

[SPX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPX/SPX) was never of any use whatsoever, because it lacked an orderly close, and even less use before SPX II because it lacked proper windowing. I found enough bugs in various platform implementations of SPX to convince myself that it was very little used. And you have to use the System V TLI programming interface, which was tedium personified.

Comment: mhmm...no wonder why wikipedia has that much info.. thanks!